# How can I display a ghost image of the last photo in Live View on a Canon camera?

Tags: canon-600d, software-recommendation, onion-skinning

I am looking for a way to make stop video - but this is really a photography question.

I am looking for a way to:

1. Shoot 1st photograph
2. When I prepare second, see the 1st with alpha/transparency to correctly fit things
3. This actually needs to work in all photos and needs to be in *live view* (just simple shoot 2 photos and fit them in photoshop took too much time)

Something like this:

[image]

For now I have 3 cameras: Canon 1100D, Canon 600D and Canon 60D - so I actually think that is possible at least in 60D - could be a Canon firmware or even a computer (OSX/Win) software.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as I know there are two possible solutions. I will explain both of them below.

### EOS utility

This software is supplied with your camera. It can be downloaded from the internet, but it's a hassle. It's better if you install it from the CD and update it.
When you have it on your computer do the following:

1. Connect your camera through USB.
2. Start EOS utility.
3. Go to `Camera settings/Remote shooting`.
4. Click on `Live view shoot`.
5. Click on `Compose` and enable the overlay image.
6. You can adjust the position, scaling and transparency of the overlay.

Now you can just shoot using Live view while seeing the overlay image. Depending on the settings of EOS utility the photos are stored on your camera or computer (or both).
This blog post has [some screenshots](http://www.p4pictures.com/2012/07/eos-utility-helps-when-shooting-composite-imagery/).

### Magic Lantern firmware

[Magic Lantern](http://www.magiclantern.fm) is custom firmware for a range of Canon cameras. Both the 60D and 600D [are supported](http://www.magiclantern.fm/downloads.html).
It adds a range of fantastic features like focus peaking, a built-in intervalometer, dual-iso, audio-triggered shooting and (useful for you) in-camera overlay images.
While it is "hacked" firmware, it is never installed on your camera and always runs from the SD card. If you don't like Magic Lantern, just format the SD card and the camera will just use the built-in firmware.

Once you've [installed ML](http://wiki.magiclantern.fm/install) on your camera(s) you can add an overlay image as follows:

1. Make sure the image to overlay is on your camera.
2. Bring up the ML menu by pushing the `Erase` button on your camera while in shooting mode.
3. You'll most probably start in the `Audio` menu. Use the arrow keys to go to the `Overlay` menu.
4. Set `Global Draw` to anything but `Disabled`
5. Enable the `Ghost Image`.
6. [Go to the Play mode, find the overlay image and press the Live view button.](http://wiki.magiclantern.fm/userguide#ghost_image)
7. You can move the overlay with the arrow keys.

<sub>I'm not taking any responsibility if your camera breaks when using ML, nor do the developers. However, I have been using the firmware non-stop for the past two years withouth any problem.</sub>

Comment: This is what I was looking for: **1)** A software to use live view mode on computer AND **2)** a firmware with no risks and even better than built-in Canon firmware. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

The unofficial firmware extension [magic lantern](http://www.magiclantern.fm/) has this feature.

There you can select an arbitrary Image that you have taken with this camera on the sd card in playback mode and overlay it in live-view mode.